# Sed only print matched expression

Tags: regex, sed

How to make sed only print the matched expression?

I want to rewrite strings like "Battery 0: Charging, 44%, charging" to
"Battery: 44%". I tried the following:

`sed -n '/\([0-9]*%\)/c Battery: \1'`

This doesn't work.

The common "solution" out there is to use search and replace and match the whole line:
`sed -n 's/.*\([0-9]*%\).*/Battery: \1/p'`
Now the .* are too greedy and the \1 is only the %.

Furthermore I don't want to match more than I need to.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

- Make the regexp a little more specific.

  ```
  sed -n 's/.* \([0-9]*%\),.*/Battery: \1/p'
  ```
- Pick a different tool.

  ```
  perl -ne '/(\d+%)/ && print "Battery: $1\n";'
  ```

  (just for the record, `foo && bar` is shorthand for `if (foo) { bar }`.)

Comment: Ah. The space in the first regexp makes it work like charm. Sadly you still have to match the whole string. I probably going to try awk.

Comment: It looks to me that even awk isn't able to do it. So i have to use full blown perl to match a string and reformat it?

Comment: @user: Are you implying there's something wrong with Perl? :)

Comment: This script is used to update the status bar in wmii, so around every second i guess. I dont know whether perl eats to much resources if used just for this purpose of rewritting a string. Guess I have to write my own tool.

Comment: @user: In that case, try bash's `[[ $val =~ regex ]]`, along with `$BASH_REMATCH`. Also, since it's battery status, consider increasing the interval to 5 or 7 seconds. (By the way, can Linux cache the Perl binary in memory after first exec?)

Comment: Somehow I always forget about Perl in these situations. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you could `grep -o` (the -o is important) for the required values instead and use those in your script(?) That way you could use the value in more creative ways or perhaps just wrapped in `echo`'s etc.

Comment: I would prefer to do it with sed (or being told it isn't possible and use awk) in case i want to extend it to do more complicated things with the string.

Comment: This is much easier than sed, and any box that has sed probably has grep also.