# Print back-reference in regular expression

Tags: shell, grep, sed, awk

I was hoping for a way to make sed replace the entire line with the replacement (rather than just the match) so I could do something like this:

```
sed -e "/$some_complex_regex_with_a_backref/\1/"
```

and have it only print the back-reference.

From [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/267416/sed-only-print-matched-expression), it seems like the way to do it is mess around with the regex to match the entire line, or use some other tool (like perl). Simply changing the `regex` to `.*regex.*` doesn't always work (as mentioned in that question). For example:

```
$ echo $regex
\([:alpha:]*\)day

$ echo $phrase
it is Saturday tomorrow

$ echo $phrase | sed "s/$regex/\1/"
it is Satur tomorrow

$ echo $phrase | sed "s/.*$regex.*/\1/"

$ # what I'd like to have happen
$ echo $phrase | [[[some command or string of commands]]]
Satur
```

I'm looking for the most concise way to do this assuming the following:

- The regex is in a variable, so can't be changed on a case by case basis.
- I'd like to do this without using perl or other beefier languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked this question on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9829169/sed-replace-entire-line-with-replacement) as well, and got [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9830004/375889) answer from potong that does what I was looking for.

```
sed '/'"$regex"'/!b;s//\n\1\n/;s/.*\n\(.*\)\n.*/\1/' file
```

Take note that it doesn't depend on knowledge of what's in `$regex` to work. It uses newlines as a sentinel value in order to later replace the entire line with just the back-reference.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know sed well enough to answer, but if you are flexible and use grep:

```
grep --only-matching "complex_regex" file
```

or

```
grep -o "complex_regex" file
```

The *--only-matching* (or the short form *-o*) flag tells grep to print out just the matched part, not the whole line.

Comment: This looks like it would be useful in cases where ignoring non-matching lines is ok. After the grep -o, a `sed "s/$regex/\1/"` would give me what I want. It's not a drop-in replacement for the fictitious sed command that replaces the entire line with the replacement text, and leaves non-matching lines alone.

Answer (score 0):

Your first .* is stopping at "day", leaving your backreference empty.  You need something definite to match against before your [[:alpha:]] in your backreference.  e.g. a space,

```
$ echo $regex
\([[:alpha:]]*\)day

$ echo $phrase
it is Saturday tomorrow

$ echo $phrase | sed "s/.* $regex.*/\1/"
Satur
```

I love and hate regexes.

---

edit:

The word boundary non-POSIX extension (\b) seems to catch both cases:

```
$ regex="\b\([[:alpha:]]\+\)day\b"
```

I'm not sure how to deal with the situation where the pattern appears multiple times or if there are multiple words in your pattern.

```
$ cat phrase.txt
it is Saturday tomorrow
it is   Saturday tomorrow
Saturday is the date tomorrow
        Saturday is the date tomorrow
Saturday is the day tomorrow
        Saturday is the day tomorrow
Saturday is the day in dayton tomorrow
        Saturday is the day in dayton tomorrow
Saturday is the day after Friday
The last day of the week is Friday

$ cat phrase.txt | sed -e "s/.*$regex.*/\1/"
Satur
Satur
Satur
Satur
Satur
Satur
Satur
Satur
Satur
Fri
```

I'm curious if somebody who's got more sed-fu gives a better answer. :-)

Comment: This works in this case, yes. However, I'm looking for a programmatic way to do this that works on any $regex variable. If, for example, $regex was `^something`, that space before it would make it fail to match anything.

Comment: See the edit... I added some stuff about \b .

Answer (score 0):

This is close to mgjk's answer, but with a slightly different approach to boundary matching.

```
echo $phrase | sed 's/.*[^[:alpha:]]\([[:alpha:]]*\)day.*/\1/'
Satur
```

Since `.*` will swallow anything, you'll have to first match "**not** the character I want" and then "the character I want". So, in `$regex` you could store

```
[^[:alpha:]]\([[:alpha:]]*\)day
```

It is not without quirks (does not work in its currect form if "Saturday" is first on the line), but if you are set on using just `sed` instead of more potent tools, then it might suffice for you. You could also do it with a two part regex to solve the "beginning of line" problem, but then it is starting to get more complex again, which you do not want. If your criteria change, many solutions exist.